# How to insert into SQL server table with multiple selected value with separated by comma?

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a table name is question.

[image]

Here I send two question and option in array by ajax. I want to insert two row in subquestion table by looping also with the option by comma separating. I get the values by this.

```
$subquestion= $_REQUEST['subquestion'];
$options = $_REQUEST['options'];
```

Here I get the multiselected values from form.

```
for (var j = 1; j <= total; j++) {
    options[j] = new Array();
    options[j][j] = $("#option_" + j).val();
}
```

Comment: Please add front-end & server side code.

Comment: Do you need to html code for form ? All code is here. How i get the values from form by jquery    for(var j=1; j<= total; j++)
        {
     subquestion[j] = $(".subquestion_"+j).val();
    }      for(var j=1; j<= total; j++)
    {
                options[j] = new Array();
                options[j][j] = $("#option_"+j).val();
            } and get the values in a page by $subquestion= $_REQUEST['subquestion'];
$options = $_REQUEST['options'];

Comment: What you want to do exactly? inserting multiple records in single insert query?

Comment: Add required code in your question, do not paste in comment box.

Comment: Yes ..please see the picture. I have two questions. I want to insert two row   by single query for each subquestion. but i have a problem for options. For first question i selected 3 options and for second i selected two options. I have a column name action in subquestion table. i want to insert options in column action by coma separated for two rows. @ Mangesh Sathe IND

Comment: @MohibulHasanRana : How does the values looks like in backend?? Could not understand where you are stuck.

Comment: Use PDO:  http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php  And instead of looping for each insert, if possible make a bulk insert statement in one string and run that.